# App Like Ovoo for video calling

Tags: ios, objective-c, voip, smpp

I am to work on an app like **Oovoo** , which supports video,audio calling , chat,photo sharing.
I have worked on voice call type app using c2call library.But donot have idea about video calling.
Is there any good library (open source/paid) which supports video calling etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this tutorial [here](http://www.iphonegamezone.net/ios-tutorial-create-iphone-video-chat-app-using-parse-and-opentok-tokbox/) uses [OpenTok-TokBox](https://tokbox.com/) and is easy to follow / understand. Maybe you want to check it.

Answer (score 1):

C2Call SDK supports Video Calling in 1 to 1 and in group conference.
Please Visit C2Call.com and see for yourself

Answer (score 0):

Try sinch https://www.sinch.com/products/video/ , it is easy to implement available for both Android and IOS

Comment: It is not free.I wanted opensource